# Question about the proof of Moran's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, proof-explanation

I'm currently reading the book "Lectures on Fractal Geometry and Dynamical Systems" by Y. Pesin and V. Climenhaga, and in the proof of Moran's theorem (page 79) it goes like this
[image]

I haven't been able to understand the last part. Let me clarify. We have a Cantor set $C$, with self-similarity constants $\lambda_1$, ..., $\lambda_k$, all less than $1$, and their sum is also less than one. The "basic intervals" are the intervals obtained in the iterations of the construction of $C$: the interval $I_{\omega_1\ldots\omega_n}$ is divided into $k$ sub-intervals $I_{\omega_1 \ldots\omega_n\omega_{n+1}}$, where each $\omega_i \in \{1, \ldots, k\}$, such that the length of the $i$-th interval is $\lambda_i$ times the length of the original basic interval. This justifies the claim that $$\lambda_{min} |I_{\omega_1 \ldots \omega_{n-1}}| \leq |I_{\omega_1\ldots\omega_n}| \leq \lambda_{max}|I_{\omega_1\ldots\omega_{n-1}}|$$

With that said, I can understand everything until it says "consequently". How were those estimates made and where did the constant $M$ come from? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$ be the number such that $|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N-1}}|>\frac{r}{\lambda_{min}}$ and $|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N}}| \leq \frac{r}{\lambda_{min}}$. Such a number always exists. Observe that for $N$ it holds
$$
|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N}}| \geq \lambda_{min}.||I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N-1}}|>\lambda_{min}. \frac{r}{\lambda_{min}} > \lambda_{min}r.
$$

Thus for $N$, we have $\lambda_{min} r \leq |I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N}}| \leq \frac{r}{\lambda_{min}}$ and this justifies the "at least 1" statement in the book. Now we want to obtain an estimate on the number $n \geq 1$ such that $|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N+n}}|$ lies between $\lambda_{min}r $ and $\frac{r}{\lambda_{min}}$. Observe that
$$
|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N+n}}|\leq \lambda_{max}^n.|I_{\omega_1 \cdots \omega_{N}}| \leq \lambda_{max}^n.\frac{r}{\lambda_{min}}.
$$
We want $n\geq 1$ such that
$$
\lambda_{max}^n.\frac{r}{\lambda_{min}} <\lambda_{min} r.
$$
From this inequality we obtain that $n> \frac{2\log \lambda_{min}}{\log \lambda_{max}}.$ Which justifies the "at most" $\frac{2\log \lambda_{min}}{\log \lambda_{max}}$ statement in the book.

Comment: Thank you very much. I still have one problem with the statement: if r is too big, it'll be impossible for the length of the basic interval to be bigger than $r \lambda_min$, right? Since the basic intervals are contained in [0,1].

Comment: From what is written you are correct. But he probably wants this estimate for r small in the proof.